# Python iterable and context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

I want behaviour as such:

```
with A() as f:
    for x in f:
        do_something(f)
```

is this the right way to do it?

```
class A:
    def __enter__(self):
        print "Entering context"

    def __iter__(self):
        for x in ["some","list"]:
            yield x

    def __exit__(self):
        print "Deleting context"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `contextmanager.__enter__` method needs to return the iterable. It *can* be `self`:

```
def __enter__(self):
    print "Entering context"
    return self
```

See the [*With Statement Context Managers* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers):

> `object.__enter__(self)`
>
> Enter the runtime context related to this object. The `with` statement will bind this method’s return value to the target(s) specified in the `as` clause of the statement, if any.

so whatever the method returns is then bound to the name given as the `as` target.

Your [`contextmanager.__exit__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__) needs to be able to accept the exception if one was raised:

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
```

When there is no exception, the `with` statement gives you three `None` arguments.

Comment: If you're just going to ignore any exception, it might be clearer to signal that in the signature by taking `def __exit__(self, *args)`. Or maybe not; I guess it's a matter of style either way.